# How to test useDispatch hook using jest and react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Hi Im working on a react project with react version 17.0.2
The test cases are written using jest and react testing library
In this project there is a functional component.

MyComponent.js

```
const MyComponent = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUsers());
  }, []);

  retrun (
    <div>Mycomponet</div>
  )
}
```

MyComponent.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useDispatch, useShallowEqualSelector } from "react-redux";

describe("Rendering the component without any failure", () => {
  const useSelectorMock = jest.spyOn(reactRedux, "useSelector");
  const useDispatchMock = jest.spyOn(reactRedux, "useDispatch");

  beforeEach(() => {
    useSelectorMock.mockClear();
    useDispatchMock.mockClear();
  });

  it("should render the accounts if more than 1 account available", () => {
    const dummyDispatch = jest.fn();
    useDispatchMock.mockReturnValue(dummyDispatch);
    expect(dummyDispatch).toHaveBeenCalled();
    const wrapper = render(<MyComponent/>);
  });
});
```

but when i run the test im getting the following error

```
TypeError: dispatch is not a function
```

Comment: [Redux Hooks](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#components)
Refer Official docs for redux hooks testing

Comment: You didn't use `useSelector`, why did you mock it? Besides, you should show the code of the `getUsers` action creator